# Creating array of buttons, then making one onClick event for all

Tags: java, android, arrays, button

I am trying to create array of buttons, then making one onClick event for all, here is my code, when I run the code I get (The application testing(processcom.MyTest.testing) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again) I am not sure what, where is the error. I must be missing something fundamental, I am not trying to create app, I am just leanring Java, specially for Android.

Here is my code

```
package com.MyTest.testing;


import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;
import java.util.Random;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class TreActivity extends Activity {
      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
//declaring some public int vars

int isPressed1 = 1;
int isPressed2 = 1;
int isPressed3 = 1;
int isPressed4 = 1;
int isPressed5 = 1;
int isPressed6 = 1;
int isPressed7 = 1;
int isPressed8 = 1;
int isPressed9 = 1;
int isPressed10 = 1;





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


   myMethod();





}; //End of onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) 

public void myMethod() { 
    MyClickHandler handler = new MyClickHandler();  

    Button[] buttons = fnButtonArray();
    for (Button button : buttons) {  
       button.setOnClickListener(handler);  
       }  
 }  


class MyClickHandler implements View.OnClickListener {  
      public void onClick(View v) { 
        Toast.makeText(TreActivity.this, ((Button) v).getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }  
 }


public Button[] fnButtonArray(){

    Button arrButtons[] = new Button[11];
      // started with 1 not 0 for the array to match the button numbers
    arrButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    arrButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    arrButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    arrButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    arrButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    arrButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    arrButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    arrButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    arrButtons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    arrButtons[10]= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn10);
    return arrButtons;

  }
  } //public class TreActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: Why do you instantiate an array of 26 elements then only fill it with 10? Also the arrays are 0-based - start with 0 not 1.

Comment: I corrected the number from 26 to 11. and I started from 1 not zero so that it match the number of the buttons. so 0 has nothing.

Comment: But the iterator is expecting an element at 0. Thus you are attempting to setOnClickListener to null since the 0th element is null.

Comment: If 0 has nothing then you can't use the for(:) syntax since this will try and assign the handler to a non-existant button.  Ideally, you should start your array at 0.  But if you continue to start at 1, you need to change this loop to `for(i = 1; i <= buttons.length; i++) { buttons[i].setOnClickListener(handler); } `

Comment: I will start from 0, and will create only 10. and I am trying this now. thanks!

Comment: You can also use `ArrayList<Button>` instead if you don't want to deal with manual arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're getting a NullReferenceException.  You create an array of size 26 but only fill the 2nd through 11th elements.  Then you loop through all 26 elements trying to assign a click handler.  When you try to assign a click handler to a null element, an exception is thrown.

You'll probably be able to see these details by checking LogCat.  You can access LogCat in Eclipse or run `adb logcat` from the terminal.

Comment: I don't think it's in the MediaPlayer.create(). I took that off and I still get the error. I also took that off from my above question code so that others that may read my questino wouldn't think this is the issue. Just to let you know my MediaPlayer.create..etc was working, I am just trying to make my code shorter by createing button array and one onclick even instead of listing 10 of them. (when I had 10 everything was working as expected).

Comment: Still thank you for trying, and for the adb logcat, I will reserch that and see how I can use it.